# What is the mistake i'm making?

Tags: python

I'm learning python from *Learn Python The Hard Way*. This is one of the exercises given, but my output doesn't matches the *What You Should See section*. [Here is the output snap. The 2nd line is printed in number 3 and the 3rd line isn't printed at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZxTp.png)

Here is my code:

```
from sys import argv 

script, input_file = argv 

def print_all(f):    
    print f.read() 

def rewind(f):   
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):    
    print line_count, f.readline()     

current_file = open(input_file)     
print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)    

print "now let's rewind, kind of like tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines: "

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Is there some problem with `readline()` in my system? This isn't the first time this happens.

Comment: I ran your code it seems to work ok if I understood you correctly. I ran on python 2.7.12, OS Xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think the `print_a_line()` function is printing it's output before it's `f.readline()` retrieves it's value.  Try adding in an extra line before the print statement.  `myLine = f.readline()` then, `print line_count, myLine`.

Comment: From print_all output you can see that there's an empty line between "this is line1" and "this is the nice line2", which you're printing in your second call to print_a_line. Perhaps some newline conversion gone awry at some point, or copy paste error?

Comment: @16num wrong guess, of course `f.readline()` is executed before the print statement and adding a variable won't change anything.

Comment: For future, please don't include console output as images in a question. It's somewhat impossible for search engines and screen readers to handle. It might also contain crucial information, such as erronous hidden characters etc.

Comment: @lecaruyer same question, different problem

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, python 2.7/3.4 running under cygwin, with both `\n` and `\r\n` line endings.  is there actually an extra newline in the input file? Try changing to be `def print_a_line(line_count, f): print (line_count, f.readline())` (passing in a tuple of the line_count and string), minor change, but it will show hidden characters in the string that way (like `\r\n`). run against the program source, it produces output like: `Let's print three lines: (1, 'from sys import argv \r\n')`

Comment: @insiyah, can you provide the input file and the output as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test.txt file contains several blank lines. You have to delete them, particularly between line1 and line2. It will solve your problem.

Without empty line :

```
First let's print the whole file:

this is line1.Say hello.
this is line2. This must be printed!!
this is line3.This is cool!Print please

now let's rewind, kind of like tape.
Let's print three lines: 
1 this is line1.Say hello.

2 this is line2. This must be printed!!

3 this is line3.This is cool!Print please
```

In your case (with empty line), you simply print the empty line starting with "2" (which means that the global variable current_line is effectively incremented):

```
First let's print the whole file:

this is line1.Say hello.

this is line2. This must be printed!!

this is line3.This is cool!Print please

now let's rewind, kind of like tape.
Let's print three lines: 
1 this is line1.Say hello.

2 

3 this is line2. This must be printed!!
```

Comment: props for noticing that the input file had a blank line.  OP didn't provide it, but of course did provide the screenshot of the output, which outputs the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am such a fool to make this mistake! I completely forgot that blank lines count too..Thanks a lot! @lecaruyer